# No linking required with some functions

Tags: c

I just encountered a strange thing. While testing math.h I tried to use pow() and compile it. I did not have to link math.h .
But when I try the same with something like fmod() I have to link math.h while compiling the programm. 
Why do I have to link the library in the second case but not in the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler may be replacing some usages of `pow` with a constant. For example, it could replace `pow(2.0, 3.0)` with `8.0`. This is a good optimisation and means you no longer need the `pow` in `math.h`.

But your compiler probably can't replace `fmod`, or all usages of math functions, so it still needs to link to the math library.